# how to make progress Bar with numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a progress bar which has to finish at 100%, and this moment the number shows this progress, the problem is this number is 1.5(it has to show 0.1, 0,2 and so on till number - 1.5)  and I don't know how bind the progress bar with this number

```
$(function() {
    var x = document.getElementById("load");
    var width = 0;
    x.innerHTML = width;
    var int = setInterval(move, 20);
        function move() {
            if (width == 100) {
                clearInterval(int);
            } else {
                width += 1;
                x.style.width = width + "%";
                x.innerHTML = width + "%";
            }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a math problem than a scripting one...

You have to tell the script that 1.5 is 100%.

I only added one line to your script in order to change the inner HTML displayed.

```
var showNumber = (1.5/100)*width;
x.innerHTML = showNumber.toFixed(1);
```

```js
$(function() {
  var x = document.getElementById("load");
  var width = 0;
  x.innerHTML = width;
  var int = setInterval(move, 200); // Setted a longer delay...
  function move() {
    if (width == 100) {
      clearInterval(int);
    } else {
      width += 1;
      x.style.width = width + "%";
      var showNumber = (1.5/100)*width;
      x.innerHTML = showNumber.toFixed(1);    // Only one decimal.
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#load{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="load"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do `width/100` and use `toFixed()` to determine the number of decimals.

```js
$(function() {
  var x = document.getElementById("load");
  var width = 0;
  x.innerHTML = width;
  var int = setInterval(move, 20);

  function move() {
    if (width == 100) {
      clearInterval(int);
    } else {
      width += 1;
      x.style.width = width + "%";
      x.innerHTML = ((width / 100).toFixed(1)) + "%";
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#load {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="load" />
```